# Using selenium with scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am trying to scrape all recorded event's table from the web-site http://southasiaterrorism.trfetzer.com/districts/17497-IND-Nandurbar.html. 
I am using scrapy spider for it, but it's not possible to get that table as it's loaded dynamically.
I was trying to use selenium, but no result, I got the same static html page without the table loaded.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, its not loaded dynamically, just check the page source inside `script` tag there is a list of all those table elements, just extract that. No need of selenium for this

Comment: but I don't see why I earn negative sign, maybe for someone it's simple, but I am newbie in all this things.

Comment: It doesnt matter, just keep learning : ) @Sirak Ghazaryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [@Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8150371/stack), the content is not loaded dynamically, it's in the page inside the `<script>` tags. You can try something like this:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    print (tds)
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966368/python-beautifulsoup-scrape-tables).

**Note:** this code is untested.

Comment: thanks, indeed the solution was in using BeautifulSoup, but I also use regexp to fetch needed data.

Comment: I suggest to use python requests instead of urllib2