# How to scrape tables using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I tried scraping tables according to the question: [Python BeautifulSoup scrape tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966368/python-beautifulsoup-scrape-tables)

From the top solution, there I tried:

HTML code:

```
<div class="table-frame small">
    <table id="rfq-display-line-items-list" class="table">
        <thead id="rfq-display-line-items-header">
          <tr>
          <th>Mfr. Part/Item #</th>
          <th>Manufacturer</th>
          <th>Product/Service Name</th>
          <th>Qty.</th>
          <th>Unit</th>
          <th>Ship Address</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="rfq-display-line-item-0">

        <tr>
            <td><span class="small">43933</span></td>
            <td><span class="small">Anvil International</span></td>
            <td><span class="small">Cap Steel Black 1-1/2"</span></td>
            <td><span class="small">800</span></td>
            <td><span class="small">EA</span></td>
            <td><span class="small">1</span></td>
        </tr>
      <!----><!---->
      </tbody><tbody id="rfq-display-line-item-1">

        <tr>
            <td><span class="small">330035205</span></td>
            <td><span class="small">Anvil International</span></td>
            <td><span class="small">1-1/2" x 8" Black Steel Nipple</span></td>
            <td><span class="small">400</span></td>
            <td><span class="small">EA</span></td>
            <td><span class="small">1</span></td>
        </tr>
      <!----><!---->
      </tbody><!---->
    </table><!---->
</div>
```

According to solution ,

What I tried is:

```
for tr in soup.find_all('table', {'id': 'rfq-display-line-items-list'}):
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    print(tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text, tds[3].text, tds[4].text, tds[5].text)
```

But this displayed only the first row,

```
43933 Anvil International Cap Steel Black 1-1/2" 800 EA 1
```

I later out found out the all those `<td>`  were stored in the list. I want to print all the rows.

Expected Output:

```
43933      Anvil International Cap Steel Black 1-1/2" 800 EA 1
330035205  Anvil International 1-1/2" x 8" Black Steel Nipple 400 EA 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You start with `tr` tag & go down to `td`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tr in soup.find("table", id="rfq-display-line-items-list").find_all("tr"):
    print(" ".join([td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')]))
```

---

```
43933 Anvil International Cap Steel Black 1-1/2" 800 EA 1
330035205 Anvil International 1-1/2" x 8" Black Steel Nipple 400 EA 1
```

Comment: I need to reorganize these lines too

Comment: Can you include the expected output in the post

Comment: Expected output is included

Comment: These values has to be organized since, I have to store them in a list.

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

While you are selecting your table with `find_all()` you would get a resultset with only one element (the table) and that is the reason, why your loop only iterate ones and print first row only.

#### How to fix?

Select your target more specific - As alternativ approach you also could use `css selctors` and `stripped_strings` to achieve your task.

This will select all `<tr>` from the `<tbody>` of element(table) with `id="rfq-display-line-items-list"`:

```
soup.select('#rfq-display-line-items-list tbody tr')
```

`stripped_strings` as generator get the strings of all the elements (the `<td>`s) in `row` and you can `join()` it to a string:

```
" ".join(list(row.stripped_strings))
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for row in soup.select('#rfq-display-line-items-list tbody tr'):
    print(" ".join(list(row.stripped_strings)))
```

#### Output

```
43933 Anvil International Cap Steel Black 1-1/2" 800 EA 1
330035205 Anvil International 1-1/2" x 8" Black Steel Nipple 400 EA 1
```